# I have copy a cnic from tbl_1 to tbl_2 and store password in tbl_2 if cnic exists in tbl_2. but password does not getting stored in tbl_2

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i want to create user CNIC account. for that i have picked a CNIC from tbl_1 and stored it into tbl_2 . And give a textbox to the user to enter only password because his cnic already exists in tbl_2. and i used "if" condition where i checked that if his CNIC is present in tbl_2 then he can enter password. but password isn't getting stored in tbl_2!!

```
 protected void btnSubmitPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "select * from userlogin";
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            MySqlDataReader msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (msdr.Read())
            {
                if (msdr[0].ToString() == txtUserCNIC.Text.ToString())
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }

            if (flag == true)
            {

                MySqlCommand mscmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into userlogin(UserPassword)values(@Password)", con);

                mscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtNewPassword.Text);
                mscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("" + ex);
        }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If then CNIC  alreay exist in table2  (userlogin)  then you should use update  and non insert  .. Insert for create a new row .. instead for change an existing row, in SQL , you need UPDATE

```
update userlogin 
set UserPassword =  @Password 
where CNIC = the_user_CNIC
```

and you should not use var in SQL you are at risk for SQL injection  for avoid this you should take a look at prepared  statement and binding param